# Value in session storage not equal to string it was set to

Tags: javascript, php, session-storage

I have a php action page which sets

```
$_SESSION["status"] = "SUCCESS"
```

when i pass this to the following page, i have a function to test if the status was set
with the following code

```
function check_status(){
        var user = sessionStorage.user;
        var status = sessionStorage.status;
        console.log(status);
        console.log(user);
        var x =status.localeCompare("SUCCESS")
        console.log(x)
        if(x === "0"){
            enter code here
        }
```

The console log returns the following

```
SUCCESS
user
-1
```

This leads to the contents of the if statement to not run. What's going on?

Comment: "when i pass this to the following page" ... how?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">sessionStorage.setItem("status"," <?php echo ($_SESSION["status"]); ?>");</script>
This is put in the page header

Comment: With this code you have an extra blank space.

Comment: I feel stupid now, many thanks. I will watch for mistakes like this in the future thank you.

Comment: Don't need to feel like this. But this kind of error are easily find when debugging your code, that you really should learn how to do.